# How to retrieve picklist value from object in visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-object, picklist, standard-objects

I have the user object in which I have defined a picklist field. The need for this is to allow certain users to only see certain records on a custom VF page. I need to get the selected picklist value for the user viewing the VF page and send to my apex controller to query a custom record. I am not sure how to proceed with this endeavour.

Thanks

Comment: Can you also provide the code snippet that you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is something you can accomplish within the Apex controller for your Visualforce page.

You'd query something like

```
User u = [SELECT My_Picklist__c FROM User WHERE Id = :UserInfo.getUserId()];
```

Then, you can use the value of `u.My_Picklist__c` to make choices about which sets of records you'd like to query and show for that user, even using the new `switch` construct:

```
switch on (u.My_Picklist__c) {
    when 'Value__one' {
        // Do something
    }
    when 'Value__two' {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Be aware that your Apex controller will enforce sharing rules and visibility, if that's part of your objective, only if it is declared `with sharing`. Otherwise, you'll query records without regard for ownership, org-wide defaults, and sharing rules.